# Can't use properties of category Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am new in JavaScript. And I have a problem at using discord.js.

```
var category = ctx.guild.channels.create("Name", {type: "category"});
console.info(category.id);
```

Output:

```
undefined
```

I can't use any properties of category.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`create()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) function returns a Promise of type [GuildChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel). So in order to store that, you need to resolve the [promise](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html#how-do-promises-work) using async-await or using `.then()` function.

Eg: Using **`.then()`** function:

```
ctx.guild.channels.create("Name", {type: "category"}).then(category=>console.log(category.id));
```

Using **async-await**:
In order to implement this, you need to make the message event as [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) in order to await the promise.

Eg:

```
client.on('message',async (ctx)=>{ //using ctx here assuming ctx is the message object in your case.
    //other functions
    var category = await ctx.guild.channels.create("Name", {type: "category"});
    console.info(category.id);
})
```

Comment: It worked. I have used second way. Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad to help you!